# ReSharper Order by "Type"

Tags: c#, layout, types, resharper

I have ReSharper 10.1 (Not 10.2 because that one is boo boo)

I love the Code CleanUp, it does wonders for me.. Except for when ordering fields.   This is what it looks like when it orders my fields..

[image]

I do not understand why it orders it like that.  To one point it does make sense because it's alphabetized, but that's what I specified,

To show you what it's supposed to look like without uploading another picture, I will just type the modifiers followed by the types.

Private readonly (I know that's not a type)

Private bool
private bool
private bool

private Color
private Color
private Color
private Color
private Color

private string

Hopefully you get gist of it as I wrote that.

There is probably no point of me showing you what I have in the settings for this because I have tried so much with no luck.

Is there any way possible I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with this using ReSharpers File Layout.

In the **Options**, under **Code Editing -> C# -> File Layout**, make sure you are under the **Default Pattern** and then you can select the **Fields** button/icon to bring up a little sub menu (properties) in the bottom right. Here you can set how and by what you want to **Sort By**. If you select **Kind** as your first option, and then **Name**, doing a Code Cleanup should get you close to the results you want.

Also, be sure to create a Code Cleanup profile with the C# -> Apply File Layout item checked to be sure it applies the layout you set above if you don't want to always perform a full file cleanup.